# How to reproduce the diagram shown in the picture in Latex?

Tags: graphics, plot, graphs

I am writing master thesis and would prefer vector graphics. Would it be possible to reproduce this graph with all the contetnt, i.e. legend, x tick, ytick, lines with arows, numbers in circles etc. ?

Is there any other way to do this, if not in Latex?

[image]

Comment: Yes it would, what have you tried, and how far have you gotten. Perhaps a simpler solution for you, would be to draw the figure in Inkscape, it can covert the output to vector graphics. Do you have the function for the blue curve?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I donot have an equation, but have an idea how it could be plotted. The curve can be essentially divided into 3 parts, horizontal line, dip (marked with 4) - this could be achieved using sine equation, and 2nd degree damping oscillation curve. The figure odesn#t have to be exact. An approximate would do.

Comment: I am working on the latex code as we speak. I am a novice user, so I am following tips and doing trial and error.

Comment: You should provide an attempt at writing the code for the blue curve using `pgfplots` ;-) I have seen similar figures being produced in the past, and I can think of a handful very skilled individuals that could help. However, some attempt / effort from the asker must be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start. As N3buchnadnezzar says, it is possible, I am just not in the mood to add all these details. Just add some arrows and circled nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \begin{axis}[ymax=5]
  \addplot[blue,very thick,samples=301,smooth,domain=-1:2] 
  {(x<0 ? 0 :-4.5*cos(x*600-acos(3/4.5))*exp(-3.5*x)+3)};
  \legend{Acceleration}
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I will make further additions :)

Comment: Schrödinger's cat, how did you evaluate formula of the curve to be  '- 4.5*cos(x*600-acos(3/4.5))*exp(-3.5*x)+3', if I may?

Comment: @ak95latexnoob This is just that the plot is continuous.